# g_hash_table_destroy() when called, does it frees up the buffer memory

Tags: c, linux, data-structures, hashtable, ubuntu-14.04

Am using GHashTable to insert key, value pairs into the table and later want to destroy the table, using g_hash_table_destroy() function, both of which happen in a loop. But while am doing so am watching the buffer/cache memory being used. As insertion is being done memory(free buffer/cache memory) is being reduced, but when destroy works the vise-versa is not being reflected.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a misunderstanding of how the application frees memory. The typical implementation is that the application doesn't return memory to the operating system; instead, the memory is simply marked as unallocated and used for future malloc() calls. So, if you call allocate a large block, populate it with data and call free(), there is no guarantee that the free() call returns the memory to the operating system.

Anyway, "free -m" is not the best way to monitor free memory. Free memory is simply wasted memory, and intelligent operating system use memory that would be otherwise free for better purposes such as caching disk files in memory. The optimal value of free memory is as low as feasible.

Comment: As far as i know "free -m" shows the buffer/cache memory(both used and free) while u run a program. Regarding your first part of answer am allocating a large block of data, populating it but am calling destroy() function of GHashTable which is very different from free() what you have understood.

Comment: @RohitBhagat If your keys and values are dynamically allocated, you have to deallocate those yourself unless you have created the hashtable with a destroy notifier. destroy() will call free() under the hood. Still, you'll propably not see any difference with "free -m", as the memory is usually not released back to the OS as juhist explains here.

Comment: @nos ok. So, g_hash_table_destroy() function release memory but not to OS, right? Then how can i keep monitor the memory being released? Is there any command for it in terminal of ubuntu??

Comment: @RohitBhagat I don't know of any easy way. You could run your program with the valgrind too, and it'll at least tell you if there's memory leaks.